# Angular Router not working in spck mobile editor

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular app with bootstrap framework. I'm developing the app in mobile phone using spck code editor. I'm trying to route my component from one to another component on button click and it doesn't seems to be working.

```
App.ts
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {RouterModule, Routes, Router} from '@angular/router'
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common'
import {PostComponent} from './component/posts/posts.component'
import {AnswerComponent} from './component/answers/answers.component'

const appRoute: Routes = [
  {path:'home', component:PostComponent},
  {path:'answers', component:AnswerComponent},
  {path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full'}
  ];
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.css']
})
export class App {
  
  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  
  goHome():void {
    console.log("home component");
    this.router.navigate(['/answers']);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoute)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [App, PostComponent, AnswerComponent],
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }],
  bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule {
  
}
```

```
App.html
<nav class="top-bar" >
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#search"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Search</a></li>
    <li><a (click)="goHome()">Quora</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="next-bar" >
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home" class="active"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#question"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#space"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#notif"><i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Question</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Topic:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="topic-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Question:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="question-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add question</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

On click it writes on console so the onclick is working properly. What's the issue with router.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're developing using Safari, Chrome, Firefox or Edge (or even IE... which I hope you're not, btw.) but try to open your dev-tools and go to the "Network"-tab.

If a network request fails when you click the link, it might be that the spck editor is not able to resolve the HTML5-navigation mechanism.

In that case, you can look into configuring the router to use the `HashLocationStrategy`, example:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

More information about the topic can be found here:
https://angular.io/guide/router